# Computing new column based on multiple rows values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
Name  Age Gender Team  
John  18    M     A 
Luke  75    M     B  
Dean  20    M     C  
Zoe   34    F     B  
Chloe 12    F     B  
Erik  56    M     A
```

And I would like to compute a new value (`TeamType`) that would be the same for all members of the team but depends on the people in the teams.
For example, team B having both `M` and `F` in the team would have `TeamType=Mixed` whereas teams C and A would be `OnlyM`, like this:

```
Name  Age Gender Team TeamType
John  18    M     A    OnlyM
Luke  75    M     B    Mixed  
Dean  20    M     C    OnlyM
Zoe   34    F     B    Mixed
Chloe 12    F     B    Mixed
Erik  56    M     A    OnlyM
```

This would be easy to do in Python or in many other traditional languages but I can't figure out how to do it in R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Team) %>% 
  mutate(newcol=ifelse(n_distinct(Gender) == 2, "Mixed", paste0("Only", Gender)))
#Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
#Groups: Team [3]
#
#    Name   Age Gender   Team newcol
#  (fctr) (int) (fctr) (fctr)  (chr)
#1   John    18      M      A  OnlyM
#2   Luke    75      M      B  Mixed
#3   Dean    20      M      C  OnlyM
#4    Zoe    34      F      B  Mixed
#5  Chloe    12      F      B  Mixed
#6   Erik    56      M      A  OnlyM
```

I went a different route than jeremycg. In the case of an all female team we should paste "Only" with the gender present.

**base R**

In `base R` it is essentially the same thing:

```
with(df, ave(Gender, Team, 
             FUN=function(x) {
               ifelse(length(unique(x)) == 2, "Mixed", paste0("Only", x))}))
```

Comment: Your approach seems to be correct when there are only 'Female' in a group.  BTW, you can use `n_distinct` from `dplyr` to replace `length(unique`

Comment: Why the need for `unique(Gender)` ? If `n_distinct(Gender) < 2` there will be only one `Gender` type no ?

Comment: It works without it. I had it in there to ensure one value only. But didn't need it.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly for me with `dplyr` ! (the technique for getting the TeamType value does not matter that much to me as my real problem is different. But now I have everything to solve it).

Answer (score 7):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Team', `if` the length of unique elements of 'Gender' is greater than 1 (`uniqueN(Gender)>1`) we term it as 'Mixed' or `else` we `paste` the string 'Only' with the first element of 'Gender' (or `unique` element of 'Gender').  Note that if there is only 'F' for a 'Team', this will give 'OnlyF'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df1)[, TeamType:=if(uniqueN(Gender)>1) 'Mixed'
                     else paste0('Only',Gender[1L]) , by=Team]
df1
#    Name Age Gender Team TeamType
#1:  John  18      M    A    OnlyM
#2:  Luke  75      M    B    Mixed
#3:  Dean  20      M    C    OnlyM
#4:   Zoe  34      F    B    Mixed
#5: Chloe  12      F    B    Mixed
#6:  Erik  56      M    A    OnlyM
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @akrun. Would also work for me but I find the `dplyr` approach more intuitive. I voted you up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr`. Here you group into subtables of each level of team, then use `mutate` to add a column - "teamtype" with the required output.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(Team) %>%
         mutate(teamtype = ifelse(all(Gender=="M"), "OnlyM", "Mixed"))

Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: Team [3]

    Name   Age Gender   Team teamtype
  (fctr) (int) (fctr) (fctr)    (chr)
1   John    18      M      A    OnlyM
2   Luke    75      M      B    Mixed
3   Dean    20      M      C    OnlyM
4    Zoe    34      F      B    Mixed
5  Chloe    12      F      B    Mixed
6   Erik    56      M      A    OnlyM
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't know why this one didn't get more votes like the others. Peeps need to be scrollin'

Comment: @RichardScriven What will be the output when the Gender is only 'F' for a particular Team?